# How do I synchronise two folders in real-time in macOS?

Tags: macos, mac, sync, real-time

im using macOS Catalina, and I want to sync two folders in real-time. One is on my Desktop for me to see and use (auto-sharing between all my os devices via iCloud), and at the same time, the other folder is on my OneDrive (for my team to see).

I want to sync both, so I don't have to always copy from the OneDrive and paste in my Desktop each time a make a change to the files.

Comment: See if this helps>>>>>>>>https://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-sync-files-and-folders-on-the-mac/

Comment: I'd also recommend rsync. If you're having trouble, if you provide some more details, I can show you how to use crontab to do it automagically. Also, have you tried soft links? It's possible OneDrive respects them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the op doesn't want to have to *run* another program to sync, but for it happen automatically.  I don't know if rsync supports a "live" mode, I've only ever used it in scripts.  So, assuming you don't want a cron job running in a tight rsync loop, let the vendor tools do the work for you.

I think you want iCloud and OneDrive to sync the same folder, but I think iCloud is very limited (only syncs Desktop and Documents, AFAIK).  OneDrive might actually be more flexible.  Create a folder on your desktop called "MyShare" or whatever.  Find the folder where OneDrive syncs and make a symbolic link to MyShare, something like this:

`ln -s ~/Desktop/MyShare .`

OneDrive *might* follow the symlink and sync it up to your public OneDrive.  If it doesn't work, try it the opposite way, creating the MyShare under the OneDrive folder, and then symlinking that to your Desktop.